# Creating a navigation system (ArcTan2)

Tags: delphi, math, navigation, trigonometry

I am currently working on a navigation system using way-points, We can define the following perimeters, assume point B is where we want to go and point A is your current location :

- We know the locations (X,Y) of both points A & B.
- Point A (you) and Point B (our destination) are both positive in their respective X and Y values.
- We know the angle Point A (you) are facing. (360 - 0 degrees)

**My question is how would I get the smallest angle to turn in order to face point B (our destination)?**

My current method is using ArcTan2(X,Y)

B := ArcTan2(Y1 - Y2,X1 - X2)

B := B * 180 / pi   ---- To convert radians into degrees.

This does return a suitable angle, but only sometimes... Other times it returns an angle that will make me face the opposite direction of point B (our destination).

Another issue I am having is figuring out if I should turn left or right - Assume we have a returned angle of 80 degrees, Should that then mean that I rotate to the left or the right ?

I hope my explanation is somewhat clear, Trigonometry was never really my strong point.

I'd be very grateful for any input or sources you guys may be able to provide me.

Thanks
MrClear

Comment: This is not a question about Delphi -- or programming. It is a question about mathematics.

Comment: Perhaps I did use the incorrect tags, This is my first post here.

However ArcTan2 was originally developed specifically for programming langues  meaning most use cases would revolve around a sort of program It seemed fitting.

Apologizes

Comment: Please - it's "angle", not "angel".  How can you write a system that depends entirely on trigonometry when you admit you know little about it?  It seems futile to recommend vectors and cross products.

Comment: @duffymo This seems rather dramatic, The only value you've added to this thread is correcting my typos x_x, Forgive me for thinking this was a forum for learning ?

Comment: I can do a lot more than that, but I think it's reasonable to expect a base level of knowledge when one claims to be writing a system that uses trig heavily.  It's not the mission of this site or the volunteers that frequent it to give you the basics.

Comment: I find your choice of Delphi surprising as well.  https://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/

Comment: @duffymo, the selection of tools is not a popularity contest foremost. The question was not about which tool to use. And Delphi is not a bad choice :)

Comment: I kind of wonder why you only have two points. Basically you want to measure an angle, and the angle is three points, not two. I had a similar task: ere you have a point O, where you ship or vehicle is, a point A from where it came, and a point B where is goes. This gave me two *vectors* A-to-O and O-to-B. There coordinates were just difference, like V1.X = O.X - A.X, V2.Y = B.Y - O.Y. Then you have two formulas to check on wiki: scalar product of those two vectors and vectoral product of those vectors. And the direction of the turn was determined by the sign of the sinus, the scalar product

Comment: Now, the worst thing i did there, it was an experiment, and i used Firebird embedded SQL for calculation. It was a lazy approach, just drop all those points (number of routes, 10K to 200K points in total) into a temporary table, and with few SQL commands you have them all calculated. No need to think about arrays, loops, etc. But, oh, it was a hell to debug, i gonna tell you :-D

Comment: There are ready made (even open source) solutions for resolving TSP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using wrong X/Y argument order

```
B := ArcTan2(Y2 - Y1, X2 - X1)
```

is correct formula to get **direction** from 1st point to 2nd one.

If you really need angle to turn, you also have to provide current direction (or previous point)

Let you are moving from point A to point B and after B you need to turn onto point C. In this case you need calculate relative angle to change direction (this approach uses cross product of vectors):

```
 CBX := C.X - B.X; 
 CBY := C.Y - B.Y; 
 BAX := B.X - A.X; 
 BAY := B.Y - A.Y;

RotationAngle := 
  RadToDeg(ArcTan2(CBX * BAY - CBY * BAX, CBX * BAX + CBY * BAY));
```

Note that function returns signed angle and you can easily check whether you need to turn left or right. Also `RadToDeg` function helps to get degrees.

Comment: I am aware that in Arctan2 you place the y value first - However that isn't the case for all calculators or libraries... I believe in Delphi specifically (the program langue I am using) you pass X first. Never the less thanks for the reply.

Comment: You can read Delphi help about Arctan2 to be ensure in Y/X order here.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the previous point ?

how would I go about adding that to equation.

Comment: @MrClear: Every time you use a new class or function in a library or API, you should read the class's or function's documentation. In this case, the documentation for Delphi's [`ArcTan2`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Math.ArcTan2) function explains that the Y precedes the X. In the Delphi IDE, if you place your cursor in the `ArcTan2` identifier and press F1, you are automatically taken to this documentation.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand thank you for clearly structured response, I've been using : https://planetcalc.com/7954/ as a proof of concept before writing it all in delphi so while that would have been any issue it's not current - Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @MrClear I added info about relative angle

Comment: @Mbo Sorry for the late reply ... Work has kept me off this project for a while.

B := ArcTan2(Y2 - Y1, X2 - X1)

Doesn't return the correct direction to the next point  take points A,B for example

A(2;1) - B(3;4)

B := Arctan2(4-1,3-2)
B:= Arctan2(3,1)
B := 71.57 degrees

If we plot those points on a rough plane we can see it isn't correct?

I've made a function to try deal with this with little success [link](https://pastebin.com/5VUQijPj)

To be clear, I just want the angel point A must face - Not must turn.

Thanks!

Comment: Direction A->B is 71 degrees indeed. Why do you think it's wrong??

Comment: @Mbo Let's use A(3,4) & B(2,3) ----- B := Arctan2(-1,-1) Therefor B := -135 
B := 360 + (-135) 
B := 225
Is it then fair to say that whenever ArcTan2(Y,X) returns a negative number we add 360 ? B := 360 + (-135)

Comment: Angle `-135` is the same as `225`. What one you have to use - depends on your needs. If you need range 0..360 (as navigation requires) - yes, add 360 when negative.

Comment: @MBo I must again thank you for your patience & advice, But I just seem to be coming up short....I've updated the calculations and it's kind of working however my idea to B := 360 + (-135)  - As explained above has caused some further problems.
[screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/Owkumm6) using real data A(4780,4282) : B(4781,4195) --- B := ArcTan2(4195-4282,4787-4780)---- B := -89  ---- B := 360 + (-89) ------ B := 271.... 271 isn't fully correct and causing us to just run past the point making almost a zigzag pattern until we reach point B, Once again any advice is amazing thanks!

Comment: Are you kidding? `274.6000956662633`

Comment: @MBo  [Angles](https://imgur.com/a/cV9r6Qw)  270 would be to the right assuming you're facing north (180) or to the left if you're facing north (360)

Answer (score 0):

If you have two points `(xA, yA)` and `(xB, yB)`, with point A as the start and point B as the destination, you have a vector from the start to the destination:

```
v = (xB-xA)i + (yB-yA)j
```

In a 2D coordinate system, with x-axis to the right and y-axis pointing up, this vector makes an angle with the horizontal axis that is easy to calculate:

```
angle = atan2((yB-yA), (xB-xA))
```

where

```
i = unit vector in x-direction

j = unit vector in y-direction
```

This angle is expressed in radians.  It rotates from the horizontal axis counterclockwise about point A.

Watch for zero length vectors.